# Should I stain/seal outdoor furniture before or after pre-drilling lots of pocket holes?

Tags: finishing, furniture, staining, outdoor

EDIT: I am using pine wood, and I intend to plug the holes if I can find xl pocket hole plugs. I do not intend for this piece to last decades. Since this is my first outdoor furniture build, if I get 10 years out of it I will be happy.

I am building an outdoor dining table. I'm using primarily pocket holes to assemble, roughly 34 XL pocket holes. If I stain and seal, then drill the pocket holes, I'll be exposing wood that is unfinished. How much does that matter for pocket holes?
[image]
Extra context in case it matters:

- table will be used in the Mid Atlantic USA, in the foothills of the Blue Ridge. Weather contains all 4 seasons, it does get pretty hot and humid in the summer but only for a couple of months.

I know this kind of question has been asked over and over, but I'm curious to know how to decide when to finish then assemble, or assemble then finish. Specifically for outdoor furniture. Does it matter the number and size of the pocket holes? I'm guessing  other modern joinery wouldn't matter since the methods don't expose as much wood as pocket holes, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. What kind of wood are you using?

Comment: The usual positioning of pocket holes may make this irrelevant unless an unusually long lifespan is envisaged. Erring on the side of caution however,  I think the usual (just preference) applies *if* you plan to fill/plug the holes.

Comment: @Ashlar I am using untreated pine wood

Comment: @Graphus I intend to plug the holes if I can find xl pocket hole plugs. I do not intend for this piece to last decades. Since this is my first outdoor furniture build, if I get 10 years out of it I will be happy.

Comment: You'll get a lot more life out of treated lumber at minimal more cost and similar appearance if stained.

Comment: @Ashlar I know but I didn’t want to wait for the wood to dry, and I don’t trust the process by which they treat the wood. They were using cancer-causing things decades ago and didn’t stop when they found out, until they were forced. So I’m not going to trust them

Comment: So when you day "pine" do you mean buying pine from a lumber yard, or SPF from a big-box? Generic softwood from e.g. Lowe's is often terrible furniture wood.

Comment: Re. plugging the holes, just look for dowel of the right diameter, and if that's not easily findable you can make your own no problem. You can saw pretty much flush with any Japanese-style saw after the glue sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I stain and seal, then drill the pocket holes, I'll be exposing wood that is unfinished.

If bare wood being exposed by the drilling is a major concern there's a simple solution: don't do it ;-)

If the intent is to leave the holes open there is basically no reason to drill them after finish application is there? So do all the drilling, then finish and all the holes can get the same level of protection as the other surfaces.

A reason to finish first and then drill is if you *want* the holes to be bare wood, to ensure good glue bonds for plugs, or proper bonding of any filler material. Although obviously finishing at the end also works fine here too.

> How much does that matter for pocket holes?

Given the typical locations of pocket holes – being hidden from view does also mean they're largely protected from weather — I'm not sure it's much of an issue really.

However, if you'd prefer to err on the side of caution then by all means protect the holes with finish, plug them or fill them. It's so little extra effort regardless of which option is selected it's more a question of why *not* do it than why do it.

Comment: Yeah, since the holes are going to be on the bottom, you'd have to have _significant_ splashing or deep snow before you get much water collecting here. Especially the holes that are in vertical pieces.